# How I can show up the context menu in chrome extension with selection function

Tags: google-chrome

I just want to know that How I can show up the context menu when I selection some text in chrome browser?

```js
function genericOnClick(info, tab) {
    // alert(info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
    // alert(JSON.stringify(info));
    // alert("tab: " + JSON.stringify(tab));

    createMenu(info.menuItemId);
}

// CREATE CONTEXT MENU
var contexts = ["selection","page"];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
    var context = contexts[i];
    var title = "My Dictionary";
    var parentId = chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "title": title, "contexts": [context],
        "onclick": genericOnClick
    });

    // Create a parent item and two children.
    var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
      {"title": "First menu1", "parentId": parentId, "onclick": genericOnClick});
    var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
      {"title": "Second menu2", "parentId": parentId, "onclick": genericOnClick});
}
```

when I submit this code without "selection action" It really working well..

but, when I selection text then after right button, It's can not working and every child menu disappear..

How I can fix this problem..